# Dribble in R: how to duplicate all i/o into a file?

Tags: r, user-interface, io

Is there something like the [Common Lisp function DRIBBLE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_dribbl.htm) or [Unix command tee](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html) in R?

Specifically, I want *everything I type* **and** *everything R prints* back to me to be appended to a file (`tee` only captures stdout; I want *everyting*: errors, warnings, print, cat, my input).

I found a [10 year old message](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-March/019247.html) on the subject which offers a weak version of that (it does not capture the output from cat/print).

The standard function [sink](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sink.html) only *captures* (not *duplicates*) the R's output; and it does *not* capture my input.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `txtStart` function (and related functions) in the TeachingDemos package.  I think that it does everything you want except capturing errors (and the `TaskCallback` system in the R guts needs to be updated for that to happen).

The other option is to run R inside of another environment such as ESS (inside of Emacs) (there are others, but I am less familiar with them).  Then everything is captured in the editor/buffer and can be saved to a file.

Note that the `sink` function does have a `split` argument that works like `tee` to show the output on screen as well as duplicate it to the file, but it still only does the output, not the input commands.

Comment: I think that I may have figured out how to include the errors even without the TaskCallback system.  So watch for a future version that captures errors as well as the commands and output.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `sink()` --  see `help(sink)` for examples.

Comment: `sink` redirects the output instead of duplicating it; it also does not capture my input, only R's output

Comment: My bad, so you want something like `tee` on the shell?  Many of us use R from Emacs' wonderful ESS mode which has features so save your buffer as a "transcript" and then re-use the transcript.  That is the closest I can think of.