# Automatically record slime repl session?

Tags: emacs, slime

How would you automatically "record" a slime repl session? By "record" I probably mean to auto-save what the repl buffer has, similar to any code buffer's auto-save. I'm sure "state" would be a much tougher issue, but at least to save the buffer contents would be a start. Of course I could just do a save C-x-s and name it something like repl20131115-111034.srepl, but to have a behind-the-scenes auto-save capability (including timestamp in the file name) would be nice.

Comment: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_dribbl.htm but I'm not sure whether slime has any special mechanism on top of it, though there's a good chance that it has.

Comment: State would not be so hard; it could be reproduced by a well-formed log of the input.

Answer (score 1):

## Psychotherapy

I asked this question about Lisp 20 years ago, [about R a year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747769/dribble-in-r-how-to-duplicate-all-i-o-into-a-file) and I am *not* asking it about python now. So, let me try to *answer* it.

## What you *asked for*

### Timed Logs

You certainly do *not* want the automatic `repl-timestamp.log` files - they will fill up your disk and you will never actually look at them.

### Auto Save

Yeah, you can save the lisp interaction buffer into a file (and then the buffer will be auto-saved periodically), but you do not want that either.

You are much better off typing your code in a buffer associated with a lisp file and sending it to the lisp interaction buffer, and only copying the "interesting" lisp output back to your file buffer. E.g., you do not want to save all 42 bad versions of a function, just the working one (and maybe a few intermediate ones - but you have git and hg for that).

## What you *really* need

What you really want it two things:

1. Remember what you did
2. Restore the state where you left off

Here is how to do that:

### Remember what you did

You can use [`dribble`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_dribbl.htm) to save into a file both what you type and what Lisp replies.
This is useful, however, I think I examined only very few of the zillions of dribble files I created in my newbie days.
They are there mostly for your peace of mind.

### Restore the state

This is what [lisp images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480083/what-is-a-lisp-image) are for: they write to disk the "state of the lisp universe" so that you can start from where you left off.